# Plot horizontal bar plot with seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm crawling a directory and reading a bunch of files and parsing them. All I need is to get the size of the dataframe. I do so by using `len(df.index)`.

Each directory has 10 files, numbered from 0 to 9. I add all these `len(df.index)` to a dataframe, where the letters`['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']` come from a list of categories. These values are added to the dataframe by `df2.loc[seed,nd] = len(df.index)`. The resulting dataframe is as follows:

```
         A         B         C       D
0  10515.0  160592.0  221621.0  198884.0
1   9777.0  161307.0  222064.0  199841.0
2  10957.0  159954.0  219553.0  198622.0
3  12731.0  157862.0  221250.0       NaN
4  11765.0  162177.0       NaN       NaN
5   8849.0  155631.0       NaN       NaN
6  10549.0  160976.0       NaN       NaN
7   8694.0  158953.0       NaN       NaN
8  11696.0  160952.0       NaN       NaN
9  10590.0  161046.0       NaN       NaN
```

In my script, I crawl two directories in a for loop, `X` and `Z`, resulting in two dataframes like the one above.

The issue is that I'm trying to plot this dataframe with Seaborn horizontal barplot using

```
sns.barplot(data=df2)
```

but I don't know how to specify the category, such as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43562577/horizontal-barplot-in-seaborn-using-dataframe/43564048).

How can this be accomplished? Do I need to change my dataframe format?

I'd like to result to be like this (from MS Excel)

[image]

Comment: What is X and Z against all these 4 categories?

Comment: Not missing column for specify categories ?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that I crawl two directories, Z and X. i will edit the post

Answer (score 22):

I think this can be achieved using the `orient` attribute of [seabon's barplot function](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html).

Example -

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
sns.barplot(data=df, orient = 'h')
```

[image: example plot]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) of both DataFrames with parameter `keys` for specify groups and then reshape by [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), last use parameter `hue` for specifying groups:

```
dfs = [df21, df22]

df = pd.concat(dfs, keys=('X','Z')).reset_index(level=0).melt('level_0')
sns.barplot(x='value', y='variable', hue='level_0', data=df)
```